# Ideal sheaf of $\operatorname{Proj}(S/J)$ is $\tilde{J}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $J$ a homogenous ideal of a graded ring $S$. Then we know that $\operatorname{Proj}(S/J)\to \operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is a closed immersion and thus it defines a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$. So let $Y\subset X$ the closed subscheme which is the image of the above morphism. Then the claim is that the ideal sheaf of $Y$ is just $\tilde{J}$. The definition I am using for the ideal sheaf, is that it is the kernel of the morphism $i^\#:\mathcal O_X\to i_*\mathcal O_{Y}$ where $i$ is just the inclusion map. I know that $\tilde{J}$ is quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals, so it must be the ideal sheaf of a uniquely determined closed subscheme $Z$, but I am having a hard time rigorously proving that $Z=Y$. I think that if I just completely untangle the definitions of $\tilde J$ and the ideal sheaf, then it would be solved but it looks very "bothersome" for such an "obvious" statement. Any hints for that would be more than welcome.

(This is a statement used on a proof of cor. 5.16 in chapter II of Hartshorne.)

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Proj} to format $\operatorname{Proj}$ - this produces better spacing. I've made the upgrade for you in this post.

Comment: Is this perhaps obvious to you on an affine open?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes it is. I think I see now how the argument goes, it just looked tedious to me at first glance and thought there would be something like a 1-line explanation for it, as Hartshorne mentioned it without any comments.

Comment: @Foivos one thing to keep in mind about Hartshorne is that once a technique is introduced (whether in the main text or in the exercises) he will often start to use that technique without comment.